# I'm trying to load a data to a table but it doesn't delete the old stuff

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-bootstrap

I have working reactJS code that loads data from an excel sheet onto a table component. If the table is empty, it works just fine. 
However, if I try to load another excel file, it only updates part of the table and not the stuff already occupied.

This is how I load a table:

```
    table = () => {
    return (<Table striped bordered hover size="sm" ref={this.configUploadRef}>
        <tbody onChange={this.edit}>
        {this.state.data.map(row => {
            return (
                <tr ref={c => this.tdRef[this.state.data.indexOf(row)] = c}>
                    {row.map(cell => {
                            return (
                                <td>
                                    <EditableLabel text={cell}/>
                                </td>)
                        }
                    )}

                </tr>)
        })}

        </tbody>

    </Table>)

}
```

And this is how I upload a new excel sheet.

```
    configFile = async configFile => {
    this.tdRef = [];
    await readXlsxFile(configFile).then((rows) => {
        this.setState({data: rows})
    }).then(
        console.log(this.table())
    )


}
```

Is there any way I can delete all of the data in the table and then populate it with the new stuff?

Comment: This sounds like it should work. The only thing I can think of is your state isn't updating correctly. Is there any way you can show us the starting state and state after getting a new sheet?

Comment: I don't see that you have any key props when you iterate over your items. Try adding a unique key for each iteration

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

Add key props, that's it.

```
<tr ref={c => this.tdRef[i] = c} key={randomstring.generate(12)}>
```

and

```
<td key={randomstring.generate(12)}>
```